# How to play music from iPad on Yamaha amplifier without AirPlay, but wirelessly?

Tags: ipad, usb, airplay

I have a Yamaha amplifier 473 series and an iPad 1 with 5.1 iOS. There is no internet connection nearby, so have to use aux but want it wirelessly through the iPad. There are av, aux and usb inputs in the front of the amplifier. How do I connect the 2 devices to play music wirelessly without AirPlay?

Comment: Airport Express.

Comment: Don't i need the internet to work it through the airport express.

Comment: So to use it I would take the ethernet cable and connect it to the airport express and the amplifier behind. Put the airport express in the power point. Wait for the green light. Then log my ipad 1 into the airport express wifi in the sttings area. Then use airplay from the music on my ipad to play.

Answer (score 2):

Just buy 2 of [this](http://www.logitech.com/tr-tr/support/wireless-speaker-adapter?crid=409&osid=14&bit=32) (or somthing doing the same job). It will transform any speaker to bluetooth speakers, so you will be able to connect any bluetooth using device to your speakers and get the sound wirelessly. You should buy one for each device you want to connect. You then can connect the two bluetooth adapter using [this](http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6221/6288671408_1254bbdcf5_z.jpg) (not sure what it is called). If your aux uses RSA, you can find the equivalent for RCA connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind about quality and cost, you can have a pair of wireless a/v transmitter and receiver. It converts 3.5mm audio output to infra red or radio frequency and back to aux.

As Matthieu Riegler said Airport expression is another option.